# Redirect home resets (qtranslate) language

Tags: redirect, language

I'm developing a website for a product (audio speaker) I'm launching and I'm experiencing an issue I can't resolve (on my own ;) ).

I've added this code to `functions.php` to disable dashboard access for subscribers.

```
add_action('admin_init', 'no_mo_dashboard');
function no_mo_dashboard() {
    if (!current_user_can('manage_options') && $_SERVER['DOING_AJAX'] != '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php') {
        wp_redirect(home_url()); exit;
    }
}
```

It works like a charm except for the fact that it resets language. i.e.: a user is logging in from page `www.example.com/en/new-user` the code above redirects him to `www.example.com` instead of `www.example.com/en`.

Is there a way to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the same method qtranslate uses to get the language parameter in the url.  Quickly glancing through the source it seems to be [`qtrans_getLanguage()`](http://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/qtranslate/trunk/qtranslate_utils.php?rev=776757#L63)

```
$url = home_url( qtrans_get_language() );
wp_redirect( esc_url( $url ) );
```

Comment: Isn't there an `exit()` missing? :)

Comment: Yes along with the rest of the code that makes up the function.  I was just giving an example.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the $path parameter with home_url as follows:

```
$url = home_url('/en');
wp_redirect($url);
```

See http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/home_url for more info

But I've just realised you wouldn't be able to hard-code the 'en' in would you.
Perhaps you could try this instead which will give you the current URL?

```
$url = home_url(add_query_arg(array()));
```

Failing that, please clarify the process. I've not used qtranslate and unsure if it uses cookies or just the URL query to find the location?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your replies. When changing my code into:

```
add_action('admin_init', 'no_mo_dashboard');
function no_mo_dashboard() {
if (!current_user_can('manage_options') && $_SERVER['DOING_AJAX'] != '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php') {
$url = home_url( qtrans_get_language() );
wp_redirect( esc_url( $url ) ); exit;
 }
}
```

I get the following error:

Fatal error: Call to undefined function qtrans_get_language() in /home/timvauk2/domains/dutchaudioworks.com/public_html/wp-content/themes/flexform/functions.php on line 1715

Did I forgot something?

Nevermind on this reply, I found out the redirect code messed up my Woocommerce checkout page somehow.
I will find another way to disable admin access…
Thanks!